# Laptop shows black screen on windows 10 but shows display on ubuntu?

Tags: display

My laptop which is dual boot ( windows 10/ Ubuntu) shows black screen while I am running windows 10 on it but give display on external monitor. In the same time there is no problem while I am switching to ubuntu it give display no need for external monitor. Remember: While I push the power button the screen is black until I am switching to Ubuntu ( use monitor). Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check Windows screen settings. Very likely the internal monitor has been disabled and can be re-enabled. It also should work with the external monitor disconnected. What happens or doesn't in Ubuntu is irrelevant, you can have completely different settings in different OSes installed in the same machine.